# Solve the equation $\frac{\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}}{x^2}=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt[7]{\frac{x^3}{x+\sqrt2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $$\dfrac{\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}}{2}-\dfrac{\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}}{x^2}=\dfrac{x}{2}\sqrt[7]{\dfrac{x^3}{x+\sqrt2}}$$ We have $x\ne0;-\sqrt2$.

Let's multiply both sides of the equation by $2x^2\ne0$ to get $$x^2\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}-2\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}=x^3\sqrt[7]{\dfrac{x^3}{x+\sqrt2}}$$$$(x^2-2)\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}=x^3\sqrt[7]{\dfrac{x^3}{x+\sqrt2}}$$ Let's multiply both sides of the equation by$\sqrt[7]{x+\sqrt2}\ne0$ to get $$(x^2-2)\sqrt[7]{x^2-2}=x^3\sqrt[7]{x^3}$$ $$(x^2-2)^8=x^{24}$$

Comment: So, where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: @Dan, I don't see how to continue the solution.

Comment: Try taking the 8th root to get a cubic equation.

Comment: @Dan, I was thinking about that but we'll get $|x^2-2|=|x^3|$

Comment: Taking the the eighth root removes a few valid solutions from the initial polynomial i think

Comment: Actually no there are only 2 imaginary solutions, 1+i and 1-i. All others are extraneous. So just take the 8th root and remove the one extraneous solution.

Comment: The only *real* solutions to $(x^2 - 2)^8 = x^{24}$ are $x = \pm 1$.  Finding all the complex solutions is a bit trickier, though.

Comment: @Kaloyan The absolute values just mean that you need to split into two possibilities: $x^3 = x^2 - 2$ and $x^3 = -(x^2 - 2)$, and solve them individually. As Dan points out, there are simple rational solutions to each of these cubics. Factor out the linear factor, and show that the remaining quadratics have no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Starting where you left off, at $(x^2-2)^8=x^{24}$, rearrange the equation to:

$$x^{24} - (x^2-2)^8 = 0$$

You *could* use the Binomial Theorem to expand the $(x^2-2)^8$ term, but for now I won't.  Just note that the polynomial's constant term (and the product of all its roots) is $-(-2)^8 = -256$.

## If you just want real solutions

By the Rational Root Theorem, any rational roots of the polynomial must be factors of 256, i.e., $x \in \pm\{ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 \}$.  It turns out that $x = 1$ and $x = -1$ are the only ones that work, and then there are no other real solutions.

## If you want complex solutions

The exponents are even, so the 24th-degree polynomial can be factored as a difference of two squares:

$$(x^{12} + (x^2-2)^4)(x^{12} - (x^2-2)^4) = 0$$

And we can do this two more times:

$$(x^{12} + (x^2-2)^4)(x^6 + (x^2-2)^2)(x^6 - (x^2-2)^2) = 0$$
$$(x^{12} + (x^2-2)^4)(x^6 + (x^2-2)^2)(x^3 + (x^2-2))(x^3 - (x^2-2)) = 0$$

Or, un-nesting the parentheses in the cubics:

$$(x^{12} + (x^2-2)^4)(x^6 + (x^2-2)^2)(x^3 + x^2 - 2)(x^3 - x^2 + 2) = 0$$

You can use the Rational Root Theorem to find one factor of each of the two cubics, and then the quadratic formula to find the other two:

- $x^3 + x^2 - 2 = 0 \implies (x-1)(x^2 + 2x + 2) = 0 \implies x \in \{ 1, -1 + i, -1 - i \}$
- $x^3 - x^2 + 2 = 0 \implies (x+1)(x^2 - 2x + 2) = 0 \implies x \in \{ -1, 1+i, 1-i  \}$

This gives us 6 of the original polynomial's 24 roots.  To find others, we can use $a^2+b^2 = a^2-i^2b^2 = (a+ib)(a-ib)$.

$$(x^{12} + (x^2-2)^4)(x^6 + (x^2-2)^2) = 0$$
$$(x^{6} + i(x^2-2)^2)(x^{6} - i(x^2-2)^2)(x^3 + i(x^2-2))(x^3 - i(x^2-2)) = 0$$

This gives us two more cubics.  There is a cubic formula that can find the roots, but they'll be messy nested-radical things.

Finally, for the sextic polynomials, use $\sqrt{i} = \pm \frac{1 + i}{\sqrt 2}$ to do the sum/difference of squares thing one more time.  Again, I'm not going to even try to write the radical forms.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Write the equation as
$$\frac{\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}}{x^2}=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt[7]{\frac{x^3(x-\sqrt2)}{x^2-2}}$$

In the transformation above, take care of the situation $x=\sqrt 2$.

$$\frac{\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}}{x^2}=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt[7]{\frac{x^3(x-\sqrt2)}{x^2-2}}$$

$$\left(\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{x}{2}\sqrt[7]{\frac{x^3}{x^2-2}}\right)=0$$

$$\frac{1}{2x^2}\left(\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}\right)\left(x^2-2-x^3\sqrt[7]{\frac{x^3}{x^2-2}}\right)=0$$

$$\frac{1}{2x^2}\left(\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}\right)\left(x^2-2-x^3\sqrt[7]{\frac{x^3}{x^2-2}}\right)=0$$

$$\frac{x^2-2}{2x^2}\left(\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^3}{x^2-2}\sqrt[7]{\frac{x^3}{x^2-2}}\right)=0$$

$$\left(\frac{x^2-2}{2x^2}\right)\left(\sqrt[7]{x-\sqrt2}\right)\left(1-\left(\frac{x^3}{x^2-2}\right)^{8/7}\right)=0$$

Comment: I cannot see how this helps OP at all.